# does MySQL automatically release the connection on a transaction rollback?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I found this earlier in someones code. As the title says, does calling `rollback` release the connection back into the pool?

**Sample**

```
router.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
  const connection = await database.getConnection();
  try {
    try {
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('1')`);
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('2')`);
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('3')`);
      await connection.commit();
    } finally {
      // all queries have executed, we can release the connection.
      connection.release();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // will this also release the connection?
    await connection.rollback();
  }
});
```

**Update**

```
router.get('/x', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const connection = await database.getConnection();
    try {
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES (1)`);
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES (2)`);
      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES (3)`);
      await connection.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      // something happened roll back
      await connection.rollback();

      // due to this finally becomes unreachable?
      throw err;
    } finally {
      // all queries have executed, we can release the connection.
      connection.release();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // error
  }
});
```

Comment: A rollback is an SQL statement that is sent through that connection. It should not affect the connection. It should be possible to use the connection to send other queries to the server. But this is only theory, it depends how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is strange, not to say incorrect. There isn't any reason to use two nested `try/catch` blocks. The way they are used they defeat the purpose of `finally`.

The code in the `finally` block is executed before exiting the `try/catch` construct, no matter how it completed.

It is executed after the code in the `try` block is executed, if it does not throw any exception or it is executed after the `catch` block is executed, if an exception is thrown (by the code in the `try` block). It even executes if the code in the `catch` block throws an exception (such an exception cannot be caught at this level, it is caught by the innermost `try/catch` block in the code that calls this function.)

Your code should look like this:

```js
router.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
  const connection = await database.getConnection();

  try {
    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('1')`);
    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('2')`);
    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO listings(num) VALUES ('3')`);
    await connection.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    await connection.rollback();
  } finally {
    // all queries have executed, we can release the connection.
    connection.release();
  }
});
```

It releases the connection at the end, either way the transaction ends.

Comment: Yeah I realized it wasn't right. However I will need two try..catch blocks because what if getConnection() throws an error. I've updated my post with my new code however what if an error is thrown, then the connection will not be released because finally is never reached? is the only way of achieving this having two release() methods?

Comment: I think I've finally come to the conclusion that if getConnection fails no connection will be made, so it won't need to be released. I'm stupid.

Comment: If `getConnection()` throws an error then there isn't any connection to release. And if it throws then the exception cannot be handled at this level. It is probably a fatal error.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. I will need to do a lot of refactoring in old code, it might not be wrong but I want it to be clean atleast.